# SQL Combine Rows into Single Row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Still cutting my teeth on SQL.  Here is my query currently (I will expand it to include all months later):

```
SELECT catid, 
CASE WHEN MONTH(expdate) = '1' then SUM(expamount) END AS 'january', 
CASE WHEN MONTH(expdate) = '2' then SUM(expamount) END AS 'february', 
CASE WHEN MONTH(expdate) = '4' then SUM(expamount) END AS 'april' 
FROM users LEFT JOIN (expcategories INNER JOIN expenses ON  catid = catid_fk) 
ON userid=userid_fk WHERE userid='1' GROUP BY catid, MONTH(expdate)
```

#### Current result

```
catid     January     February     April
1         123.0000    NULL         NULL
2         NULL        500.000      NULL
1         NULL        NULL         505.0000
```

I would like the results for a particular `catid` to return on a single row, such as:

#### Desired result

```
catid     January     February     April
1         123.0000    NULL         505.0000
2         NULL        500.000      NULL
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?   2000,2005,2008, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: remove `MONTH(expdate)` from the `GROUP BY` clause, and move each `SUM` to encompass its `CASE` clause - like so:

```
SELECT catid, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(expdate) = '1' then expamount END) AS 'january', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(expdate) = '2' then expamount END) AS 'february', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(expdate) = '4' then expamount END) AS 'april' 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN (expcategories INNER JOIN expenses ON  catid = catid_fk) 
ON userid=userid_fk WHERE userid='1' 
GROUP BY catid
```

(Alternatively, consider using SQLServer's `PIVOT` functionality.)